# Using PHP preg_replace for this regex

Tags: php, regex

I have two awesome strings:

`my_awesome_string`
`my_awesomestring`

I'm trying to create a function that can convert the first underscore to a `/` if there is a second underscore in the string, but convert it to a `-` if there is no second underscore.

`my/awesome-string`
`my-awesomestring`

Can you help me convert my awesome string?

Comment: Must this be done by a regex? Or can it be something else?

Comment: can be done with whatever. my brain went to regex but i suppose that doesn't have to be the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way:

```
$first = strpos($str, '_');          // find first _
$last = strrpos($str, '_');          // find last _
$str = str_replace('_', '-', $str);  // replace all _ with -
if($first !== $last) {               // more than one _ ?
    $str[$first] = '/';              // replace first with /
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example code does what you asked for, I found it rather trivial as there is a function to count how often a string is part of a string (could be replaced with the char counting function as well). [Demo](http://codepad.org/CYboIEei):

```
<?php

$strings = array(
    'my_awesome_string',
    'my_awesomestring'
);

function convert_underscore($str) {
    $c = substr_count($str, '_');
    if (!$c) return $str;
    $pos = strpos($str, '_');
    $str = str_replace('_', '-', $str);
    ($c>1) && $str[$pos] = '/';
    return $str;
}

print_r(array_map('convert_underscore', $strings));
```

Comment: my strings won't be entered into the function as an array, but rather one at a time. what exactly would need to be changed in that scenario? anything?

Comment: sorry, missed the array_map at the bottom

Comment: I think the answer Felix gave is a little more elegant, but thanks for introducing me to `substr_count`!

Comment: @Dave Kiss: Yeah, it's a nice solution he made.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this should work:

```
if( substr_count($str, '_') > 1 ) $str = preg_replace('/_/', '/', $str, 1);
$str = str_replace('_', '-', $str);
```

Comment: You can't use the third parameter of str_replace to limit the number of replaces. Would be nice to have that though, but it's missing ;)

Comment: You are using `str_replace` wrong: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php the fourth parameter is a variable to which the number of substitutions will be assigned. It can't be used to *control* the # of substitutions.